# Problem Ajax with list 5000+ items

Tags: sharepoint-online, ajax

I created a js online in Sharepoint 2013, with $ .ajax with conditions .... $ filter = ...
Everything works with the list less than 5000 record otherwise error threshold.

The data that I receive are about 100-200 record

I have read several articles but I did not understand what is the right solution to the problem

You help me?

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is not to have over 5000 items per list as SharePoint online has a limit that you cant go around.

What you can do is make views on the list you created.

1-4999
5000-9999 and so on. based on item ID column in SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it means creating more views sorted by ID, but ajax can read records of the views?